# Detecting when a method is completed in WinRT (C#)

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I'm working on an app for Windows 8. I have a C# class called "User". User has a method called authenticate. My method looks something like this:

```
public class User
{
  public bool IsAuthenticated { get; set; }

  public async void Authenticate(string username, string password)
  {
    // Code to build parameters and url is here
    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(myServiceUrl, new StringContent(json, String.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
    JsonObject result = JsonObject.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
  }
}
```

The Authenticate method works. Its successfully hitting my service and returning the appropriate details. My question is, how do I detect when this method has completed? I'm calling this method in response to a user clicking a "Login" button in my app. For instance, something like this:

```
private void loginButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  User user = new User();
  user.IsAuthenticated = false;
  user.Authenticate(usernameTextBox.Text.Trim(), passwordBox.Password.Trim());

  if (user.IsAuthenticated)
  {
    // Allow the user to enter
  }
  else
  {
    // Handle the fact that authentication failed
  }
}
```

Essentially, I need to wait for the authenticate method to complete its execution. But, I don't know how to do this. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to make `Authenticate()` return `Task` instead of `void`.
The returned `Task` (which is generated by the compiler) will give you information about the status of the asynchronous operation.

You need to make the event handler method `async` too.
You can then `await` the result of your other `async` method.

---

In general, you should never use `async void` methods except as event handlers.